# How to reply to the user DM via Slack API?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, slack, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

My setup is as follows: I have Dialogflow bot added as an app. The bot interacts with Slack and Dialogflow. The script uses dialogflow_fulfillment to handles the requests to return the response back to Dialogflow. At the same time, I want the bot to interact with the users like questionaries or buttons without routing back to Dialogflow. I can get it to post messages to any specified channel using client.chat_postMessage(). However I want to the bot to reply directly to the user when the user DM the app. I am not sure how this can be achieved. Please advise.

[image: I want to reply to the app, not the channel]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using one app to monitor another app is not allowed by Slack. So this was not possible. The only possible way is to merge it to one app and use event api on it.